# Weird Characters in Python when reading a file's name

Tags: printing, sign

Code:

```
path5 = '2.Project\WP101 (237641784)\QR2\5.Project\\'
print ('path5 =',path5)
```

I get:

```
path5 = 2.Project\WP101 (237641784)\QR2.Project\
```

What can I do to stop getting the weird sign after QR2 in the path name?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! You're probably facing some encoding issue. Try putting in a `r` in front of the string like so: `r'2.Project...'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ignore escape chars.

```py
    #ignoring escape sequences

    #ignoring single quote escape sequences
    str1 = r"Hi, I\'m IncludeHelp"  
    #ignoring double quotes escape sequences
    str2 = r"\"Hello world\""
    #ignoring path escape sequences
    str3 = r"D:\\work_folder\\python_works"
    #ignoring hexadecimal values escape sequences
    str4 = r"This is  \x49\x6E\x63\x6C\x75\x64\x65\x48\x65\x6C\x70"

    print(str1);
    print(str2);
    print(str3);
    print(str4);
```

Just put an r infront of your string and you are good to go.

In your case:

```
path5 = r'2.Project\WP101 (237641784)\QR2\5.Project\'
print ('path5 =',path5)
```